# Objective-C: Create week-day-number to name mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

**EDIT Start**

Ok, obviously I didn't make myself clear.

1. I need a "first-day-of-the-week"-independent bi-directional mapping of days of the week. So although the user might change his/her locale/region settings the stored day-numbers can still be used to identify the "correct" days.
2. I know of `NSDateFormatter`'s and `NSCalendar`'s `weekdaySymbols` methods. **But I couldn't find any documented direct relation between the indices of the returned array and the value found in `NSDateComponents`' `weekday` property in the API/Apple docs.** Yes, there are a lot of posts (here and elsewhere) doing like `[NSCalendar weekdaySymbols][dateComps.weekday - 1]` (or even `[NSCalendar weekdaySymbols][dateComps.weekday]`). But, apart from the fact that I had problems mapping the day-IDs back to weekday of an actual `NSDateComponents` (see second code snippet from original post), I prefer being sure before handing over the project to a/the client.
3. The problem I encounter with the first code snippet (posted in my original post) is that `NSCalendar`'s `dateFromComponents:` doesn't honor the `weekday` property of the passed `NSDateComponents` instance.

**EDIT End**

Hi I'm trying to build a day-number (like 1 for sunday) to day-name (like "sunday") mapping. So that I can present the list of days (Monday to Sunday or Sunday to Monday or whatever follows the user's calendar-preferences) to the user. The mapping is needed, so that I can store the number(s) of the days the user selects in a localization independent way.

I know of `NSDateFormatter`'s or `NSCalendar`'s `weekdaySymbols`. But as I understand that these are just lists, without a relation to the user's preferences (in terms of first-day-of-week) or *dayOfWeek* (as might be returned by a `NSDateComponent`s instance), I don't see how I might use those.

I tried several approaches....but something always breaks the thing up.
The following version for example starts fine with *Monday* as the first value assigned to `dayName`. But further iteration don't seem to have affect on the date. So I get a list of 7 *Monday* strings.

```
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSDate *date = nil;
    NSString *dayName = nil;;

    NSDictionary *idToNameDict = nil;
    NSInteger weekday = [cal firstWeekday];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        dateComps.weekday = weekday;
        date = [cal dateFromComponents:dateComps];

        dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

        idToNameDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dayName forKey:@( dateComps.weekday )];

        [tempArray addObject:idToNameDict];

        weekday++;
        if (weekday > 7) {
            weekday = 1;
        }
    }
```

In short, I have the following requirements:

- User-calendar dependent presentation (start/end of week) of days of the week
- Save the days the user selects in a non-localized way (as kind of *day-ID*)
- Check what ever date if it "matches" one of the days selected by the user before.

I surly have missed something. But I can't seem to find the missing part.
Before I used just the `weekdaySymbols` and added `1` to the element-index to map the *day-ID* to the name. But then the following code hat e.g. `weekday` with a value of `2` for a Tuesday, whereas when building up the list Tuesday was associated with `3`.

```
NSDate *givenDate = ...; // from somewhere
NSInteger userSelectedDay = ...; // from data store
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:givenDate];
if (comps.weekday == userSelectedDay) {
    // highlight or whatever    
}
```

It might has todo with time-zone "stuff", but as I never set (or remove) the timezone, I can't see how/where.

Comment: repeated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330420/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-a-day-of-the-week-in-the-users-locale

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316614/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-from-a-given-number

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you're asking. `weekdaySymbols` is already, and always, a mapping from weekday number to name. It doesn't change with the calendar's `firstWeekday`.

Comment: @Shoaib: Not a duplicate as far as I can see. As I stated, that I know about `weekdaySymbols` method(s). I've updated my post so that it might get clearer where my problems are.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Is  `weedaySymbols` _already, and always, a mapping from weekday number to name_? The docs provided by apple, at least as far as I found them, doesn't state this.

Comment: @dergab you mean to say id 1 is not equal to Sunday for all locales? what is the device locale, you are testing on?

Comment: @Shoaib, no I haven't encountered a situation, where day-ID `1` is not Sunday. But on the other hand I couldn't find Apple stating, that **A)** the (e.g.) Sunday symbol of `weekdaySymbols` is and will be always on index `0`, and **B)** Sunday (or how it might be named in other languages) will always be reflected as `weekday == 1` of `NSDateComponents`.
It seems to me, that I will have to implement the application logic _assuming_ this (-> A) and B)). But I would have preferred to have a clear statement from the API/Apple docs on this. ;)

Comment: Source:  [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) <!ATTLIST day type ( sun | mon | tue | wed | thu | fri | sat ) #REQUIRED >

Comment: WRT the updated question point: 3: From the Apple docs `NSCalendar dateFromComponents`: "Unnecessary components are ignored (for example, Day takes precedence over Weekday and Weekday ordinals)." A date can't be created given a weekday, there are several date possibilities and day defaults to 1.

Comment: Thanks, @zaph. This would explain the 7-Mondays problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

> The timezone used is the users when the data is created.
>   Sunday == 1

Weekday number from a date:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger weekdayNumber = dateComponents.weekday;
```

Day name from a date:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE";
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Week name from a number:

```
NSArray *weekDayNames = [[NSDateFormatter new] weekdaySymbols];
NSString *weekDayName = weekDayNames[2];
```

Comment: Thanks @zaph for the examples. But as I stated, I know about the `weekdaySymbols`. And my code snippets as well showed that I know about `NSDateFormatter`,  `NSCalendar and `NSDateComponents` classes and their usage as such. I've updated my post to be (hopefully) clearer regarding my problem(s).